# SOAP service using sudzc only returns boolean 'true' on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, soap, boolean, sudzc

I am using http://sudzc.com/ to implement SOAP service call on my iPhone app. the service was written for Login details, which is supposed to return the value true or false according to the login. When I am calling the service it always returns the value 'true'. I have checked with the wrong email and password but the return value remains true.

here is my code

```
 - (IBAction)whenLoginButtonPressed:(id)sender
  {

   MFLSoap *service=[[MFLSoap alloc]init];


   [service Login:self action:@selector(handleFind:) Email:emailField.text Password:passwordField.text Token:@"B3A8FFA7F863"];
  }

 -(BOOL)handleFind: (BOOL) result 
  {
    if (false) 
      {
         NSLog(@"false value");
      }

    else if(true)
      {

         NSLog(@"true  value");
      }


    return result;
  }
```

it returns only true value   :(

Comment: What values you get when you print result?

Comment: it only gives true. i tried with wrong login , again it gives the value true only

Comment: Test web service first through browser.. It may happened your web service have problem

Answer (score 0):

Your handleFind: method is flawed. if(false) will always fail, if(true) will always succeed. Your NSLog will always be "true value" regardless of the state of result. The correct code is:

```
-(BOOL)handleFind: (BOOL) result 
  {
    if (result) 
      {
         NSLog(@"true value");
      }
    else 
      {

         NSLog(@"false  value");
      }
    return result;
  }
```